# javascript convert / to division sign with fractions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert '/' into ÷... which I can do when there are no fractions involved...

30÷2 works

30 1/2÷2 doesn't work

30 1/2÷2 1/2 doesn't work

I want it to be able to work with with or without spaces before or after the ÷.

This is what I have so far but the I have multiple / they all get changed to ÷...

[jsfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/frankn/072xbymw/4/)

```js
<input class='formula replaceSlash' type="text" id="cabHeight" name="cabHeight" size="9" maxlength="30" onkeypress="validate_numbers(event);"/>

var divSign="\u00f7";
    
if (divLength==1){
    if (!this.value.match(/\s\d\/\d?/)){
        var updatedText=this.value.replace(/(\/)/, divSign);

        if(updatedText!=this.value){
           this.value=updatedText;
        }
    }
}
if (divLength==2){
    if (this.value.match(/\d\/\d?/)){
        var updatedText=this.value.replace(/(\/)/, divSign);

        if(updatedText!=this.value){
           this.value=updatedText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your html & show where `divLength` comes from. Provide a [mcve] & preferably create a snippet which replicates the issue

Comment: @admcfajn thanks for your suggestions...  I added the html but unfortunately I've never used code snippet so I'm not sure what else to add... I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: @admcfajn I added a jsfiddle link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out... probably better ways of doing it but it works...

changes I made...

`if(divLength==2)` to `if(divLength==2 && !this.value.match(/\u00f7/)`

`var updatedText=this.value.replace(/(\/)/, divSign);` to `var updatedText=this.value.replace(/\/([^\/]*)$/, divSign);`

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankn/072xbymw/29/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `g` flag on the Regexp, so it can go over the same string multiple times replacing the desired character.

```js
var divSign = "\u00f7";
const test1 = "30/2";
const test2 = "30 1/2/2"
const test3 = "30 1/2/2 1/2"

const res1 = test1.replace(/\//g, divSign);
const res2 = test2.replace(/\//g, divSign);
const res3 = test3.replace(/\//g, divSign);

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
console.log(res3);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's exactly what I want to avoid... it should look like this 30 1/2÷2... not 30 1÷2÷2. My bad my explanation isn't the best.